# Left join is not working on codeigniter

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter

I am new in code `igniter`. I am trying to execute `delete` query using joining multiple tables, but I am getting error in query.

Here is my query code.

```
$this->db->from('order');   
$this->db->join('item_order', 'item_order.order_id = order.order_id','left');
$this->db->join('product', 'product.product_number = item_order.item_number','left');
$this->db->join('product_to_image', 'product_to_image.p_id = product.products_id','left');
$this->db->join('product_to_dropbox', 'product_to_dropbox.products_id = product.products_id','left');

$this->db->where('order.user_name', $ebay_user_name);
$this->db->where('order.user_id', $user_id);

$this->db->delete('order');
```

Comment: is `'orderd'` on purpose or just a typo?

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Is it about non unique identifier by any chance?

Comment: I am getting only order table deleted.

Comment: Please explain what you want to delete from which tables.

Answer (score 0):

When using Codeigniter you can not perform a `DELETE` with `Join`. [see here](https://www.adherewebdesign.com/joins-codeigniter-active-record-delete/) and [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#CI_DB_query_builder::delete).

You need to write a natural SQL. See link 1:

```
$sql = "DELETE o FROM order as o
  LEFT JOIN item_order ON item_order.order_id = order.order_id
  LEFT JOIN product ON product.product_number = item_order.item_number
  LEFT JOIN product_to_image ON product_to_image.p_id = product.products_id
  LEFT JOIN product_to_dropbox ON product_to_dropbox.products_id = product.products_id

  WHERE order.user_name = ? and order.user_id = ?";
$this->db->query($sql, array($ebay_user_name, $user_id));
```

OR try with backticks `. But I'm not sure whether or not escaping them:

```
$sql = "DELETE o FROM `order` as o
  LEFT JOIN `item_order` ON item_order.order_id = order.order_id
  LEFT JOIN `product` ON product.product_number = item_order.item_number
  LEFT JOIN `product_to_image` ON product_to_image.p_id = product.products_id
  LEFT JOIN `product_to_dropbox` ON product_to_dropbox.products_id = product.products_id
WHERE order.user_name = ? and order.user_id = ?";
$this->db->query($sql, array($ebay_user_name, $user_id));
```

Comment: I am getting this error above query->   
A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order FROM `order` LEFT JOIN item_order ON item_order.order_id = order.ord' at line 1





Line Number: 695

Comment: According to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html the `Delete` syntax was correct. But maybe it wants an alias... Which MySQl Version are you using?